# Its possible get PIN and PUCK code from sim card?

Tags: android

anyone know - its possible to get

```
 "PIN CODE"
 "PIN2 CODE"
 "PUK1 CODE"
 "PUK2 CODE"
```

from sim card??
im using this code for getting other info like : sim number, sim operator, sim serial.

```
 List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfos = SubscriptionManager.from(context).getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
        for(int i=0; i<subscriptionInfos.size();i++)
        {
            SubscriptionInfo subInfo = subscriptionInfos.get(i);
}
```

but how about pin/puk codes? I need get it programmaticaly without "special number call"

Comment: If you could pull the PIN and PUK codes from the SIM, they would be completely useless.

Comment: from other side - its not possible?